# cordova.file.applicationStorageDirectory requires permission. Is there an alternative?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugin-file

I have static app assets that I keep in the www folder. I read the assets using cordova.file.applicationDirectory. On iOS it works perfectly, but on Android the user needs to grant permission access to the library.

When I store files in cordova.file.cacheDirectory and cordova.file.dataDirectory the user doesn't need to grant any permissions.

I don't want to bother the user with the permission dialog as I am only reading files from my own app bundle.

Is there an alternative place to store the files? The files should be included in the app and not downloaded.

Is it possible to put static assets in the cordova.file.dataDirectory? And if yes, how to I manually add files to the location?

Comment: have you tried `cordova.file.applicationDirectory` for android? it seems to fit for assets, and is read-only

Comment: so both `applicationStorageDirectory` and `applicationDirectory` are requesting permission on android? it shouldn't for the first one at least (see android quirks in https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/ ) on which version are you testing?

Comment: applicationStorageDirectory does not require permission, but how to I get to my www folder from applicationStorageDirectory?

Comment: I looked in the app container and there is no way to get to the www folder from applicationStorageDirectory. The www folder is in a different path. This is really annoying.

Comment: of course, didn't think about that.. can we know what is the type of the assets (and so why you want to access it from file rather than an URL)?

Comment: I have templates in www/assets that I read as text. After reading the file I replace some markers inside the file with content and store a generated file in the cacheDirectory. I also copy a couple of other assets like images, etc from www/assets to the cacheDirectory. If there is another place I can put the files where I can use readAsText and copyTo that would also solve my problem.

Comment: what you try to do seems indeed cleaner than what i did for the same problem. I used an ajax call to get these kind of files, with the advantage that it works in some other environments. If you find a solution with your way, or know downsides to ajax, i would be curious to know